# How do I define a tabularray column that is right aligned with width of 50mm?

Tags: tabularray

Trying to build a table that has defined width columns. The manual hints that I can define width, but its vague.

How do I define a right-aligned column with a width of 50mm?

as a MWE

```
\begin{tblr}{colspec={m{25mm}m{100mm}Q[r,wd=50mm]|}}  
         & name \newline tagline &  phone\newline email \newline address\newline Linkedin   \\  
\end{tblr}
```

What I noticed is that the last line is right aligned, but the ones above it are centred

[image: mwe-output]

Comment: with `Q[r, wd=50mm]` ?

Comment: I probably just have to do a multi-row?

Comment: You should not mix the `tabularray` syntax with syntax of `array`  (`tabular`). Please, consult `tabularray` package documentation. BTW, where you need multirow? This is not evident from your question. Please provide complete small document with your table, which we can compile as it is.

Comment: It works if you use `{phone\\ email \\ address\\ Linkedin}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me complete my comment by an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[r, wd=50mm]},
            hlines, vlines}
right   \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
See, if the following change of your code fragment gives what you after:

- for the first two columns are used `Q` column type of desired width and left aligned content
- for breaking of text in cell is used `tabularray` syntax `{first line\\ second line}`

```
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l,m,wd=25mm]Q[l,m,wd=100mm]Q[r,wd=50mm]},
             vlines}
    & {name\\ tagline} 
        &  {phone\\ email\\ address\\ Linkedin}     \\
\end{tblr}
```

I can't show result of above code fragment since it the page layout and used document class are not known. If you will provide this information, I will be able to extend it to an MWE.

BTW, this table is very wide, so it may happen, that it will protrude right border of a page and content of the last column will not be visible.

Comment: updated my question to cover off some weirdness with the right align

Comment: @baradhili, please, provide MWE, which reproduce your problem and illustrate with sketch what you after!